# Credit card money transfer

Tags: secured-credit-card

I have a job offer where I would be purchasing items with the company's money with them transferring money to my credit card account without the card number, is that possible some how?

Dino

Comment: `credit card account without the card number` Some more details would make it much clearer.

Comment: Sounds like fraud to me.  You buy them items, ship to their address, they never pay you.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you chose the tag "secured-credit-card" instead of just "credit-card"?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot transfer money to a credit card account. You can transfer balances, or pay off the card with money from a bank account. Even if you could transfer money to a credit card, there's no way to do it without the credit card number.

As Pete B. pointed out, this does sound like fraud.